# How can I target child of specific parent with click effect using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to find out how to edit this jQuery code so that only the parent whose button is clicked shows its child. At the moment, all the children are shown when any button is clicked, not the one nested in the targeted parent.

I have tried using

```
$(this).find(".child").toggleClass("open");
```

but this didn't work.

Any help much appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/jf1ya0cz/2/

**HTML**

```
    <div class="parent">
     <div class="child">
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent">
     <div class="child">
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent">
     <div class="child">
     </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .parent {
      position:relative;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      background:red;
      display:inline-block;
      float:left;
      margin-right:6px;
    }

    .child {
      width:inherit;
      height:30px;
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
      background-color:blue;
      opacity:0;
      transition:0.5s;
    }

    .child.open {
      opacity:1;
    }

    .button {
      float: left;
      background: yellow;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    $( "<span class='button'></span>" ).insertBefore( ".child" );

$(".button").click(function() { 
        $(".child").toggleClass("open"); 
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$(this).find(".child")` you need to use [`$(this).next(".child")`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) because `.child` here is not the child element of `.button` but the immediately following sibling of the `.button` instead. So, your code will be like:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("<span class='button'></span>").insertBefore(".child");

  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".child").toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.parent{position:relative;width:100px;height:100px;background:red;display:inline-block;float:left;margin-right:6px}
.child{width:inherit;height:30px;position:absolute;bottom:0;background-color:#00f;opacity:0;transition:.5s}
.child.open{opacity:1}
.button{float:left;background:#ff0;width:40px;height:40px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the big mistake you were making was you are using .child selector on click this will select all the elements attributed with this class name. There are many ways you can achieve this, You can achieve this using Vanilla Javascript there is no need for Jquery too. Here is my approach.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

 
$(".parent").click(function(e) { 
   e.target.firstElementChild.classList.toggle("open")
 }); 
 
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  margin-right:6px;
}

.child {
  width:inherit;
  height:30px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:blue;
  opacity:0;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.child.open {
  opacity:1;
}

.button {
 float: left;
 background: yellow;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
   </div>
 </div>
```